# Ionic - How to remove header title?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to remove header title in ionic? I want to remove `login` title inside my header.

my code

```
<ion-view  hide-back-button="true">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  <h1 class="title"><img class="title-image" src="img/header_logo.png" /></h1>
   </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/home/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Current issue

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
<ion-view title=''>
```

Put any html content inside title and it will re rendered as html.

```
<ion-view title='<img class="title-image" src="images/logo.png" />'>
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your view

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" hide-back-button="true" view-title="welcome">
```